# QtQuick - qml:28: Error: Unknown method return type: custom type

Tags: c++, qt, qml

### What am I trying to do

I have two classes `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`. `ObjectA` is a composition of `ObjectB`.
I want to make a button that calls the function `insert(int num, ObjectA &A)` from `ObjectB` in QML.

#### My code:

**objecta.h**

```cpp
//...

#include <QObject>
#include <QDateTime>

class ObjectA
{
public:
    explicit ObjectA(QString str);
    //...    

private:
    //...
};

//...
```

**objectb.h**

```cpp
//... 

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>
#include "objecta.h"


class ObjectB : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    ObjectA generate(QString str);
    void insert(int priority, ObjectA &A);

public:
    ObjectB(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    //...
private:
    //...

};

//...
```

**objecta.cpp**

```cpp
include "objecta.h"

ObjectA::ObjectA(QString str)
{
    //...
}
```

**objectb.cpp**

```cpp
include "objectb.h"

//Object A is a composition of Object B

ObjectA ObjectB::generate(QString str){

    ObjectA *A = new ObjectA(str);
    return *A;
}

// ^ I will use the *A as the parameter for the &A in function insert()
void ObjectB::insert(int num, ObjectA &A){ 

    //...
}

//...
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include "objectb.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ObjectB B;

    qmlRegisterType<ObjectB>("com.mycompany.ObjectB", 1, 0, "ObjectB");

    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

import com.mycompany.ObjectB 1.0

Window {
    //...

    ObjectB {
        id: objectb
    }

    Page {} //Page.qml
}
```

**Page.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Row {
    id: row
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 20

    TextField {
        id: strfield
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: numbox
        width: 200
        model: [ "1", "2", "3" ]
    }

    Button {
        id: btninsert
        text: "Insert"
        highlighted: true
        onClicked: objectb.insert(numbox.currentIndex+1,objectb.generate(strfield.text))
    }

}
```

#### The Error I got

When I click on the button, I get this error message:

```
qrc:/Page.qml:28: Error: Unknown method return type: ObjectA
```

I think the problem is on `objectb.generate(strfield.text)` failed to return `ObjectA` since QML can't recognize the custom type. How can I solve it?

**Edit:** Added header files of `ObjectA` and `ObjectB`, and cpp file of `ObjectA`

Comment: you need to register ObjectA as well (I only see ObjectB in main). If wanted you can use `qmlRegisterUncreatableType`

Comment: @Amfasis I get `issue: no member 'staticMetaObject' in 'ObjectA'` after declaring `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<ObjectA>("com.mycompany.ObjectA", 1, 0, "ObjectA","code");` in `main.cpp`. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Did you use ```engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("objectb", &B);``` in your *main.cpp*? and also can you share ur *objectb.h* file ?

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I just added `objecta.h` and `objectb` file on my question. Also updated `main.cpp`. I didn't use `engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("objectb", &B);` in my `main.cpp`.

Comment: @MaxKu `ObjectA` misses the `Q_OBJECT` macro, that's why you get that error

Comment: @Amfasis Adding a `Q_OBJECT` macro means I need to make the class `ObjectA` inherit from `QObject`. Doing this gives me `issues: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'ObjectA'` from `objectb.cpp`, `issues: copy constructor of 'ObjectA' is implcitly deleted because base class 'QObject' has a deleted copy constructor` from `objecta.h`, and `issues: 'QObject' has been explicitly marked deleted here` from `qobject.h`. btw I updated the cpp file of `ObjectA`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MaxKu sorry, I missed that. In that case you can still try it with `Q_GADGET` (and a qmlengine register)

Comment: @Amfasis I added `Q_GADGET` in my `ObjectA` header and `qmlRegisterUncreatableType<ObjectA>("com.mycompany.ObjectA", 1, 0, "ObjectA","code")` in my `main.cpp`, also added `import com.mycompany.ObjectA 1.0` in `main.qml`. The Error `qrc:/Page.qml:28: Error: Unknown method return type: ObjectA` still pops up when I click the button. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @MaxKu the last resort I can think of is to add a `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ObjectA)` in your header. If that also fails you might be able to get it work with `QVariant::fromValue` but that's not so nice of course (although newer versions of Qt seem to prefer that)

Comment: @Amfasis Can you show me where should I add a `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ObjectA)`? I tried adding it inside the class `ObjectA` and it tells `class template specialization of 'QMetaTypeId' must occur at global scope`, so I am adding it outside the class in the header but then it gives me `issue: no matching constructor for initialization of 'ObjectA'`.

Comment: @MaxKu you should add it outside the class, in the header (although cpp can also work). Also be sure to do it outside any namespaces (but include them in the reference to ObjectA if any)

Comment: @Amfasis It pops up `issue: no matching constructor for initialization of 'ObjectA'` if I add it outside the class, in the header. I guess I will just try to merge `generate()` and `insert()` into 1 function in order to avoid creating custom return type in QML. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution:

Avoid using custom return type in QML.

**objectb.h**

```cpp
//... 

#include <QObject>
#include <QList>
#include <QDebug>
#include "objecta.h"


class ObjectB : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    // A new function that combine both generate and insert function
    void btnInsert(int priority, QString str)

    ObjectA generate(QString str);
    void insert(int priority, ObjectA &A);

public:
    ObjectB(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    //...
private:
    //...

};

//...
```

**objectb.cpp**

```cpp
include "objectb.h"

//Implement new function
void ObjectB::btnInsert(int priority, QString str)
{
    ObjectA *A = new ObjectA(str);

    //Code implementation...
}

//Object A is a composition of Object B

ObjectA ObjectB::generate(QString str){

    ObjectA *A = new ObjectA(str);
    return *A;
}

// ^ I will use the *A as the parameter for the &A in function insert()
void ObjectB::insert(int num, ObjectA &A){ 

    //...
}

//...
```

Note the `onClicked` in `Button`.

**Page.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Row {
    id: row
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    spacing: 20

    TextField {
        id: strfield
    }

    ComboBox {
        id: numbox
        width: 200
        model: [ "1", "2", "3" ]
    }

    Button {
        id: btninsert
        text: "Insert"
        highlighted: true
        //Modified
        onClicked: objectb.insert(numbox.currentIndex+1,strfield.text)
    }

}
```